# Difference between vector::push_back and string::push_back?

Tags: c++, string, vector

What is the difference between vector::push_back and string::push_back?

I know that string::push_back removes the last character of a string, if I'm not mistaken. Although, I'm not sure what is vector::push_back.

Since they are the same name, I'm guessing they do the same thing but differently? Does vector::push_back remove the last element of a vector, or add a new element to the vector?

Comment: Both functions does the same thing: It adds something to the end of the container. See e.g. [this `std::vector::push_back` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back), or [this `std::string::push_back` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/push_back).

Answer (score 1):

Seriously, why didn't you google this?

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/push_back/
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/

String's one adds a character to the end of the string. Vector's one adds an element to the end of the vector.